# Recommended way of passing instructions to processes in MPI?

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi

Suppose I want to use MPI for simulating vector clocks. I initially wanted to make a file that specificied the behavior of the system:

```py
4        # number of processes
10       # number of actions
# actions can be event, send i or receive i
0 event  # index of process and respective action
1 send 0 # send clock from 1 to 0
3 event
1 send 2
2 receive 1
...
```

The plan would be for a shell script to read the first line, pass it as an argument to `mpiexec -n` and the rest of the file would be the program.

However, I'm having a hard time of reading such a file and passing its instructions to the respective processes.

Three approaches I thought:

- have the process 0 read the entire file, parse it and pass an array of instructions to each of the other processes. This approach, however, seems a bit cumbersome.
- allowing processes to read the whole input file and make them ignore those lines that don't describe an action about it (for example, process 2 would ignore every action not specified with index 2). sounds clumsy, however
- don't use files and hardcode the actions. terrible, requires recompilation on each changez pollutes the source, etc

Since I'm relatively new to MPI and distributed systems, I'm not sure if these are all my options, neither the best of them for this use case.

Thanks.

Comment: The second approach is best, especially with respect to performance (i doubt this is critical here though) and memory footprint. An other option is to pre-process this file before running your MPI program so each rank can open its own input file.